# Windows Azure: detect client location

Tags: azure

We have an application that is deployed on Windows Azure.  The application serves client apps installed on Windows Phone devices.  Now I an facing a new requirement - filter clients based on their location (more accurately, based on the location of the operator).  The requirement is to filter out certain blacklisted countries (like Iran etc.)

I know that in Google App Engine, any incoming HTTP request has a header which specifies location of client.  wanted to know if there;s anything resembling that on Azure.

Answer (score 1):

No, Azure doesn't have any mobile-specific features for geo-location of IPs.

A general list of resources that may help you are here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283016/know-a-good-ip-address-geolocation-service.

Bear in mind, however, that if your user is behind some kind of proxy or VPN that they can circumvent this kind of check *very* easily as their IP will appear to be different.